# - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {} is not working

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I called the method,

```
     - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [self.name resignFirstResponder];
    [self.userName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.mailId resignFirstResponder];
    [self.password resignFirstResponder];
    [self.reTypePassword resignFirstResponder];

      }
```

for the purpose of resign first responder.it is working properly without using scrollview.but if i am using scrollview i cant able to use this method.why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a gesture recognizer if you need to use a scrollview.
Try this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignFirstResponder:)];
 gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
 [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];


-(void) resignFirstResponder:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
 {
    [self.name resignFirstResponder];
    [self.userName resignFirstResponder];
    [self.mailId resignFirstResponder];
    [self.password resignFirstResponder];
    [self.reTypePassword resignFirstResponder];

 }
```

There are many more alternatives: See 
[UIScrollView prevents touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded on view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439273/uiscrollview-prevents-touchesbegan-touchesmoved-touchesended-on-view-controlle) ,
[UIScrollView touchesBegan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685956/uiscrollview-touchesbegan/17759373#17759373)