# ScrollView - Gesture Recognizer - Swipe vertically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, scrollview

I have a UIScrollView that works when swiping left or right, however I've reduced the size of the scrollView so, now display area doesn't fully occupy the superview's frame, and swiping works only within the frame of the scroll view.

I would like to be able to scroll vertically even when swiping up and down outside the horizontal bounds of the narrowed scroll view.

It was recommended that I use a gesture recognizer, but that's beyond my current familiarity with iOS and could use more specific advice or a bit more guidance to get started with that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43328905/5173807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler approach then use a Gesture Recognizer =]

You can setup the superview of the scroll view (which is BIGGER...) to pass the touches to the scroll view. It's working M-A-G-I-C-A-L-Y =]

First, select the view that will pass all it's touches to the scroll view. if your parent view is already ok with that you may use it. otherwise you should consider add a new view in the size that you want that will catch touches.

Now create a new class (I'll use swift for the example)

```
class TestView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var Scroller: UIScrollView!

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event)

        if (view == self) {
            return Scroller
        }

        return view

    }

}
```

Nice! now as you can see we added an outlet of the scroller. so use interface builder, select the new view and set it's class to "`TestView`" in the **identity inspector** (Or to the name that you'll use for your custom class).

After you set the class and your view is still selected go to **connections inspector** and connect "`Scroller`" to your scroll view on the storyboard. All connected properly =]

That's it!! no gesture recognizer needed!!
The new view will pass all it's touches to the scroll view and it'll behave just like you pan in it =]

In my answer I used [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7719901/2830676)

**EDIT:** I improved the code now, it wasn't working as expected before, now it catches only when in needs and not every touch in the app as before

Comment: Its working. But can you plz do it using gesture recognizer?

Comment: Instructor asked to do it using gesture. Thats why.

Comment: It's harder (and less elegant - good for learning only), I think you should open a new question.. I hope you'll find it

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for a component called `SwipeGestureRecognizer` : 
   [image]
2. Grab it and drop it on top of the View (use the hierarchy to make sure 
   you drop it on it, if you drop it on another element this code will not work):

   [image]
3. Select one of the `SwipeGestureRecognizer` in the hierarchy and go to its attribute page. Change Swipe to Right.

[image]

4. Make sure the other recogniser has the Swipe attribute to Left

[image]

5. Select `UIScrollView` and uncheck Scrolling enabled

[image]

6. Connect `detectSwipe()` (see source code below) to both recognizers.

--

```
@IBAction func detectSwipe (_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (currentPage < MAX_PAGE && sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left) {
        moveScrollView(direction: 1)
    }
    if (currentPage > MIN_PAGE && sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right) {
        moveScrollView(direction: -1)
    }
}



func moveScrollView(direction: Int) {
    currentPage = currentPage + direction
    let point: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(currentPage), y: 0.0)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)      

    // Create a animation to increase the actual icon on screen
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
        self.images[self.currentPage].transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)
        for x in 0 ..< self.images.count {
            if (x != self.currentPage) {
                self.images[x].transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to https://github.com/alxsnchez/scrollViewSwipeGestureRecognizer for more

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time for detailed answer but:

In storyboard drag a pan gesture recognizer on the scroll view's superview... Connect it's action with your view controller and in this action change the scroll view position by using the properties from the gesture recognizer that you got as parameter

**Tip:** when connecting the action change parameter type from `Any` to `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in the combo box

**please don't see this answer as recommendation to use this approach in your problem, I don't know if that's the best way, I'm just helping you to try it**

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answere. I'll try it out when I'm back home and comment if it works.

Comment: It helped you??

Comment: I've tried that but I had no time to comment this again, sorry. 
I tried to understand what you've said and I coded this as far as I understood. Now, I don't really now what the gesture recognizer properties are so I just put this piece of code in ViewController.swift:     @IBAction func ScrollOver(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        scrollView.frame.size.width = 320
}
As I said the scrollView is smaller than the superView but the scrollView has a color so with this extra code I've written the scrollView size grows and the color with it so it kinda didn't what I want to do.

Comment: Does it catch touches outside the color as you requested?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Only within the color.

Comment: So you attached the gesture to the scroll view instead of its parent, if you connect it to the parent you'll get touches even from outside the color and you'll just need to set scrolling offset by the gesture properties

Comment: Oh sorry, I understood it wrong. 
Yea, it does catch touches from outside the color. 
I tried it with >> print("Test") << when I try to swipe/slide the screen outside the color, it prints Test. 

But I don't know what you mean with "you'll just need to set scrolling offset by the gesture properties" where are them

Comment: Now I'll try and if success I'll give you a detailed answer

Comment: Success! I'm posting a new answer... It's working and it's without the gesture recognizer =]

Comment: the answer by @yitschak is woking perfect but he missed one thing...create a new cocoa touch class and paste this code in that and do the rest as he says