# Can't scroll both UIScrollView in UITableViewCell and the UITableView itself

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

My pure AutoLayout `UITableViewCell` looks like this in Interface Builder:

```
UITableViewCell
|-> UITableViewCell.contentView
    |-> UIView (ScrollViewContainerView)
        |-> UIScrollView
            |-> left (fixed)
            |-> center (fill remaining)
            |-> right (fixed)
```

The `UIScrollView` contains a `left`, `center`, and `right` `UIView`. `left` and `right` are both fixed width, while `center` expands to fill the remainder of the `UIView`. The `UIScrollView` constraints are to align all edges to `ScrollViewContainerView`. `ScrollViewContainerView` constraints are to align all edges to the `UITableViewCell.contentView`. I have a constraint on `center`'s width to be a multiple of `ScrollViewContainerView`'s width, so the `UIScrollView` scrolls left and right, but the height is fixed and does not scroll. Note that the `UIScrollView` has been subclassed to include [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061620/277718) so that the `UITableView` can detect a tap on the cell to toggle selection.

The issue is that I currently can either scroll the `UITableView` containing these `UITableViewCells` up and down *or* I can scroll the `UIScrollViews` in the `UITableViewCells` left and right, **not** both.

When `ScrollViewContainerView.userInteractionEnabled == YES`, I can't scroll the `UITableView` up and down, but I can scroll the UIScrollView left and right. When `ScrollViewContainerView.userInteractionEnabled == NO`, I can scroll the `UITableView` up and down, but I can't scroll the UIScrollView left and right. `userInteractionEnabled == YES` on everything else in the above hierarchy.

I *can* get away with having `ScrollViewContainerView` as a sibling view to the `UIScrollView` (making the `UIScrollView` the direct descent of `contentView` -- can't get rid of this view completely, because I require it to get the dimensions for the `UIScrollView` `frame`). In that case, the opposite handling with `userInteractionEnabled` holds.

I know I've done this before in other projects before, but starting fresh again, I can't seem to figure out what step I'm missing. Currently using Xcode 6 6A215l targeting iOS 8, though I have reproduced the issue under Xcode 5 targeting iOS 7.

Comment: What iOS are you using? I am doing currently something similar in a project and it works on 7. I was even able to scroll vertically the scroll view, when I messed up the vertical constraints and the content size got bigger than the frame in height.

Comment: @Levi My previous projects targeted iOS 7 and worked. I'm re-implementing this on iOS 8 now.

Comment: Woah woah woah! Why are you using a scrollview inside a tableview cell?

Comment: Could you try and run it on an iOS 7 device and let me know how it goes? Because if this doesn't work because of the OS version, I am going to have a problem too

Comment: @LordZsolt How else would you display a content that needs to be laid out horizontally and exceeds the width of the cell?

Comment: @Levi same situation under iOS 7 via Xcode 5. I'm sure this *should* work, I'm just blocking the responder chain somewhere along the line and am not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user2277872's answer put me on the right track to look at the output of the `UIScrollView` delegate methods of the `UIScrollView` in my `UITableViewCell` subclass. Putting an `NSLog()` in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` made me notice that the `UIScrollView` *was* receiving scrolling events while I was trying to scroll the `UITableView`. My `UIScrollView` had a `contentSize` larger than its frame in **both** directions, but I've forced that view to only scroll horizontal, so ignored the height and reset it. That force was my undoing and I should have known it at the time -- the correct solution is to fix the frame height. If the `UIScrollView` doesn't think there is more vertical content, it will correctly forward the swipe up/down gesture to the `UITableView`.

While I attempt to figure out why my `contentSize` is too large when it wasn't before (thinking I'm missing a `clipToBounds` somewhere), what I'm doing to force horizontal scrolling temporarily is (in the `UITableViewCell`'s subclass):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
        [super drawRect:rect];

        CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
        contentSize.height = self.frame.size.height;
        self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
}
```

**EDIT**: Actually, this is seemingly better than overriding `drawRect`. This would be in the `UIScrollView` subclass:

```
/*
 * Lock to horizontal scrolling only.
 */
- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize
{
    [super setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentSize.width, 1)];
}
```

The `height` `struct` member isn't too important, as long as it's guaranteed to be smaller than the `frame.size.height` of the `UITableViewCell`. Still hacky, still need to find why I could clip before and not now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the scrollview is causing your tableview to not allow userInteraction when being scrolled. I'm sure that if you called `- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` in the UIScrollView delegate (not sure for iOS 8), but you could just do

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
         if(scrollView.dragging == YES) {
            self.<scrollViewName>.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
         }
 }
```

This is untested code, but it's just a bit of help to get you where you need to go.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I met some similar problem.

I have a scrollView in tableViewCell. All works fine.

Until one day, someone told me that the tableView can't scroll up/down when finger is touched on the scrollView in 6p. Just in 6p, not in 5, 5s,or6.

This makes me almost crazy.

Finally, I set the scrollView's height smaller than the height in storyboard.

Biu ~ It works~~~

Still, I don't know why.

Comment: "Finally, I set the scrollView's height smaller than the height in storyboard." this sentence save my life :) it really works. I have smiliar issue. And I see your answer and problem solved. Thanks.