# How to handle touches by an UIView on top of a UIScrollView and the UIScrollView both at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have the following hierarchy, the root view of the controller. Added two subviews, a standard UIView and a UIScrollView. The UIView is on top.

What I want to do is to receive touches on that UIView, meaning touchesBegan, touchesMoved... like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Began")
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Moved")
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    next?.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Ended")
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    next?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

But at the same time I want the scroll to work. The UIScrollView that is below, I want that to keep scrolling as usual.

This seems impossible to do. If my view handles touches, then I can't forward them to the UIScrollView. But I want both things: see the raw touches on the top view while the scrollview to work as usual.

How can I accomplish this?

The opposite would also work. Meaning, a scrollview on top that scrolls as usual but I also receive the raw touches (touchesBegan, touchesMoved...) on the view that is underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061620/10953499) worked for me, though with some slight changes. Do note that for this solution, the UIScrollView is on top of the UIView. Firstly, you need to create a subclass of UIScrollView and override the touch methods.

```
protocol CustomScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewTouchBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    func scrollViewTouchMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    func scrollViewTouchEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
}

class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {
    
    var customDelegate: CustomScrollViewDelegate?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        for gesture in self.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
            gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            gesture.delaysTouchesBegan = false
            gesture.delaysTouchesEnded = false
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        customDelegate?.scrollViewTouchBegan(touches, with: event)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        customDelegate?.scrollViewTouchMoved(touches, with: event)
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        customDelegate?.scrollViewTouchEnded(touches, with: event)
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}
```

Take note of the code in `awakeFromNib()`. UIScrollView has its own set of gestures. So for each gesture, `delaysTouchesBegan` and `delaysTouchesEnded` needs to be `false` to prevent delays for the touch events.

Finally, just assign the delegate to your ViewController and implement the methods like so.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: CustomScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var touchView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.customDelegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: CustomScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewTouchBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Check if touch location is within the bounds of the UIView
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: view)
            if touchView.bounds.contains(position) {
                print("Began")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func scrollViewTouchMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Check if touch location is within the bounds of the UIView
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: view)
            if touchView.bounds.contains(position) {
                print("Moved")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func scrollViewTouchEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // Check if touch location is within the bounds of the UIView
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: view)
            if touchView.bounds.contains(position) {
                print("Ended")
            }
        }
    }
}
```