# How to capture touch events from a UIScrollView when user is scrolling the screen vertically on iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, touch, swiftui-scrollview

I'm new to the iOS development and Swift and I have the following problem:

I would like to capture touch events from the screen. I have no problems with doing this on regular views. Unfortunately, I encountered issues with the `UIScrollView` component. When user is tapping on the screen, long pressing on the screen or moving finger horizontally, then I'm able to capture touches, but **when user is moving finger vertically** and activating vertical scrolling at the same time, **then I'm not able to capture touches**.

I found a few threads on StackOverflow regarding similar issue, but solutions provided there did not resolve my problem.

Structure of my views is as follows:

```
+- View (top-level view)
   |
   |
   +--- UIScrollView
        |
        |
        +-- other views inside...
```

Here is my code:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addGestureRecognizer(myRecognizer)
  }
}
```

Gesture recognizer is added into the top-level view.

I also have basic custom implementation of the `UIGestureRecognizer`:

```
class MyRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        // handle events...
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        // handle events...
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        // handle events...
    }
}
```

**What did I try to do to solve this issue?**

- setting parameter `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = false` - didn't help
- setting parameter `scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false` - I was able to capture all touch events, but scrollView stopped working - didn't help
- adding gesture recognizer to the scrollView and removing it from the top-level view - didn't help
- adding gesture recognizer both to the scrollView and the top-level view - didn't help
- setting parameter `scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` - I was able to capture all touch events, but scrollView and all UI components stopped working - didn't help
- reordering calls in `MyRecognizer` class: handling events first and then calling method from the upper class `super.touches...` - didn't help

Right now, I have no idea what else I can do to capture touch events inside the `UIScrollView` while user is scrolling the screen vertically.

Any suggestions or help are appreciated!

Regards,

Piotr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So UIScrollView has its own set of gestures that have `cancelsTouchesInView` set to true by default. Try setting this property to `false` for each gesture in the scrollview like so:

```
for gesture in scrollView.gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
    gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
}
```

**EDIT**:

Solution to this problem is creating a separate custom `UIScrollView` and capture touches inside it. It is described in details in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594220/10953499 (also linked in the comment).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately, It didn't help.

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate. I do have a more detailed answer for a similar question, though it involves creating a subclass of UIScrollView. If you'd like you can try refer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70594220/10953499)

Comment: Thanks for this link. I will check it out. I'd rather avoid creating a subclass of this view, but maybe that's the only solution in this case.

Comment: Finally, I used proposed path with the custom `UIScrollView`, you provided in another thread. I edited your reply and marked it as a solution to my problem. Thanks.