# Getting screen coordinates from UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement a UILongPressGestureRecognizer in an iOS app. It fires as expected, but I don't see anyway of passing screen coordinates to my target method. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This seems to work as an action:

```
- (void)receivedLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
     CGPoint coords = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
}
```

I still don't really understand (it seems like the last touch point is stored in the gestureRecognizer, in which case I would expect there to just be a property or something). But hey, it works.