# Creating a words grid for a search word game

Tags: ios

I want to draw a words grid that user can select the wrods, like the image below

[image]

I think the best way is to use a UICollectionView element for draw a grid but how can I handle touch events and mark selected letters?

Comment: So your question is basically "I want to copy this app, do it for me please" You need to try something first and come back with actual errors, questions, or other roadblocks.

Comment: @zimmryan - Dude chill! Obviously he's a newbie asking help for some overall design ideas. We've all been there.

Comment: @ zimmryan I don't want to copy this app... there is something on my mind but of course I won't tell what exactly I am going to make and what is my idea, please make little sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one answer to your question. You could use individual UIButtons for each letter or set up your own touch coordinate tracking system corresponding to letters or do something completely different. It boils down to what you feel comfortable working with and your experience level. To get the ball rolling, I would suggest you take a look at this Ray Wenderlich [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33804/how-to-make-a-letterword-game-with-uikit-part-1) which shows how to create a letter word game by dragging letter tiles. The tech in this tutorial will definitely help you with your project.

Updated:
If you go the button route, you can create them programmatically and pretty much do anything you want. Change their title (in your case) letter, show or hide them, track various kind of touches, and so on. For the letters and tracking touches, there are probably a number of methods of doing this. Try putting your letters on a subview while keeping track of their center coordinates. Then add a new subview over your letters to track the user's touches.

You will have to read and understand the [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class.

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721864/getting-screen-coordinates-from-uilongpressgesturerecognizer) of how to get a user's screen coordinates from a touch.

Comment: Actually I need to find a way to select UICollectionView cell's because I want to create a dynamic grid which user can add, remove and select elements. I guess I can't do this with only buttons.

Comment: I can handle touch events and the letters on the grid user touches but I don't know how to get the letters user swipe over?

Comment: I think I understand where I am going to start. Thank you..