# Why isn't tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath being called for my UITableView contained within a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I dropped a `UITableView` onto the `UIView` which is contained within my `UIScrollView`. I've got the delegate and data source set to my `UIViewController`, but I notice that the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method isn't being called. I don't have `touchesBegan` or any other touches* method overridden. I tried the 4th answer here: [UIScrollView touchesBegan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685956/uiscrollview-touchesbegan) subclassing my `UIScrollView` but the method is still never called. The table cells are populated correctly though.

Comment: post some code about how you add your tableview?

Comment: Check user interaction of uitableView. It should be enabled??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dont implement any UITapGestureRecognizer on UIScrollView. or touchesBegan in UIScrollView Class. and it will work.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that the tap gesture recognizer would be the culprit. Sooooo since I actually need this tap gesture recognizer, is there a way to make them both work?

Comment: - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return ![NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"];
}

Comment: I completely looked over that thought. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly that the `UITableView` is a subview of a `UIView`, and that the `UIView` is a subview of a `UIScrollView`?

For what it's worth, this worked fine in my iOS 7 simulator (I was receiving the `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` messages). Here's a view controller you can use to test out my implementation.

```
@interface ContainedScrollersViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *tableViewContainer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *values;
@end

@implementation ContainedScrollersViewController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        int countValues = 20;
        _values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:countValues];
        for (int i = 0; i < countValues; i++) {
            [_values addObject:@(arc4random() % 100)];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    _tableViewContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
    _tableViewContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    _tableView.delegate = self;
    _tableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:_tableViewContainer];
    [_tableViewContainer addSubview:_tableView];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    self.scrollView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    // arbitrary sizes to visualize each view in the hierarchy
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(640.0f, 960.0f);
    self.tableViewContainer.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 600.0f);
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.values.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"selected row:%i", indexPath.row);
}

@end
```