# Adding Long Press Gesture Recognizer to Google Map in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6

I added a GMSMapView to a UIScrollView and also i added Table View to that UIScrollView. No my task is if Long Press on any Location on the Map i will get that address and add that address to Table View and also i want to add a marker at that Location.

I write the Below code for adding long press gesture recognizer to the map but it is not working.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self->map.delegate = self;
    CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIScrollView  *scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    scroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320,1000);
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:21.0000 longitude:78.0000 zoom:4.5];
    map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,390) camera:camera];
    [scroll addSubview:map];

    UITableView *tab = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 410, self.view.bounds.size.width, 300) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [scroll addSubview:tab];

    tab.delegate = self;
    tab.dataSource = self;

   UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapLongPress:)];
   longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.5;
   [map addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
}

-(void)mapLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
  {
    if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
      NSLog(@"%f",coordinate.latitude);
      NSLog(@"%f",coordinate.longitude);
    }
  }
```

The Main Problem here is "mapLongPress" method is not called after i long press on the MapView.
 Can any one Help me please.

Comment: this is because scrollview is not responding to your gesture.  try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685956/uiscrollview-touchesbegan/17759373#17759373

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use default MapVIew LongPress event

```
  /**
 * Called after a long-press gesture at a particular coordinate.
 *
 * @param mapView The map view that was pressed.
 * @param coordinate The location that was pressed.
 */
     - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView
    didLongPressAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```

Comment: Thanks for u r answer.But it is not Working.

Comment: map = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width,390) camera:camera];
map.delegate = self;

Comment: @SunnyShah check out my quest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329911/google-maps-delegate-method-bug please same usage but my `didLongPress...` delegate never gets called while all other GMS del's do. Not sure what's happening...