# touchesBegan in UIScrollView called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which has been `subclassed` to get the touch events. There is a UIView inside the `UIScrollView` and the `UIView` in turn has several subviews.

So basically the structure is `UIScrollView` > `UIView` > `UIView's`.

The `UIView's` has been given a `tag` so as to detect the view which was tapped.

But the `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is fired twice whenever I  tap the `UIView`.

What might have gone wrong?

I subclassed the `UIScrollView` as mentioned here : [Touches Began](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685956/uiscrollview-touchesbegan).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, only while iPad, and noticed that the touches param was the same, e.g. with 
    `po touches` in the LLDB console gave me exactly the same data, excepted the "location in view".
I interpret this that another view forwarded the event, in this case the main `UIWindow`, so tried:

   `UIWindow *theMainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
   theMainWindow.gestureRecognizers = 0;`

It works. I verified that the iPhone version still works fine (with Pan and Zoom).