# How to get the long pressed point in MapView. Google Maps SDK. Swift

Tags: ios, google-maps, touch, point, gmsmapview

For the mapView, I create it by `self.view.addSubview(mapView!)`, so I guess that's why I can't override the touchesBegan function to detect the touch point. There is a function called `didLongPressAtCoordinate` in mapView delegate, but it only contains coordinates and mapView as argument.

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didLongPressAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

For the implementation, you can check the solution given in this SO post - [UIScrollView touchesBegan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685956/uiscrollview-touchesbegan/17759373#17759373).

Aside from that, explanation and sample code given in this blog - [How to perform action when user taps on map using MapKit, Swift](http://www.e-howtogeek.com/255492/how-to-perform-action-when-user-taps-on-map-using-mapkit-swift) might also help.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. But still doesn't work. I created a scroll view and add the MapView in like this self.view.addSubview(mapViewTouchView) mapViewTouchView.addSubview(mapView!). I am thinking is it because once the view detect the long press, the didLongPressAtCoordinate function will get called first