# IOS 5: UIScrollView not pass touches to nextResponder

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touches

I have a subclass of `UIScrollView`, and override all 4 Touches functions for it. In those Touches functions, 
`[[self nextResponder] Touches...]` and `[super Touches...]` are used to pass the touches events.

Also I have a view controller in which I override all 4 Touches functions too. In the Controller, I set the `self.view` as: `self.view = subclass of UIScrollview;`

Before iOS 5, when there are touches move on the scrollview, the view controller's touch functions can receive all touch begin/move/end/cancel calls. But in iOS 5, they can't, only one `touchesBegan` and one `touchesMove` are received.

From the log of the code, touch functions in the `UIScrollView`'s subclass are always called.

Also, If I set the `subclass.enableUserInteraction=NO`, the touches function in view controller will be called well. But I need the scrollview to have interaction with user, so I can't set it to no.

Is there anything different I missed in iOS 5? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

There is a very simple work around :)

Instead of:

```
[self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
```

Use:

```
[[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
```

Works also for touchesBegan & touchesEnded.

That's it! Problem gone! Now the touches events are passed to the next responder :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an iOS 5 bug.  See this SO post:

[touchesMoved not firing in iOS5 for the iPhone for UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794783/touchesmoved-not-firing-in-ios5-for-the-iphone-for-uiscrollview)

"As mentioned before I logged a defect with Apple, they finally got back to me. And I quote: 'After further investigation it has been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being investigated by engineering.". They give the original bug ID #10213937. They give thanks for submitting the bug, but do not offer any workarounds.'"

Still not sure how to solve for iOS 5 unfortunately.