# iOS - touchesMoved called only once in subclassed UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, subclass, touchesmoved

I am trying to drop movable UIImageViews within a subclassed UIScrollView so that I can drag them around my UIScrollView.  I subclassed UISCrollView and the dropping behavior is working, but when I try to drag the images, touchesMoved is only evaluated once.  The touchesMoved method in my subclass of UIScrollView looks like this:

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    if (!self.dragging) {
        [self.nextResponder touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event]; 
    }else{
        [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    }        
}
```

It is being called continuously during a moving touch, as it should.  Can anyone think of a reason that the touchesMoved method in my view controller would only be called once?

Comment: Tried setting `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`?

Comment: Yes, I've set userInteractionEnabled.  I should mention that upon a touchesMoved event, the imageView does move slightly in the direction that I start moving.

Comment: Ah btw you're calling `[self.nextResponder touchesMoved:withEvent:]` which is explicitly prohibited by Apple's docs. Instead of sending to self.nextResponder, send to super.

Comment: **And read the docs.** The same thing is written in UIView's class reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not sure exactly what you're suggesting.  I got the structure of my subclass from here: http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html but I saw a lot of similar things in other StackOverflow posts.  When I change it to [super touchesMoved: touches withEvent:event]; the method isn't called at all.

Answer (score 5):

[IOS 5: UIScrollView not pass touches to nextResponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485853/ios-5-uiscrollview-not-pass-touches-to-nextresponder)

Instead of:

[self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
Use:

[[self.nextResponder nextResponder] touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];