# Pinch and zoom in iphone imageview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a scrollview over which a series of imageviews a placed.I want to have pinch and zoom effect on it.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read  [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) in apple Doc and try to search for "zoom", You will get all the variable and method associated with zoom feature in scrollView by yourself.

Check SO forum post

[How do I programmatically zoom a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172255/how-do-i-programatically-zoom-a-uiscrollview)