# How to pinch view on button press?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I've got the button on the fullscreen UIImageView and I want to pinch this view on that button press. I mean, I want to show only the part of the UIImage to the fullscreen after the button is pressed. Which method should I use?

Comment: Where are you doing the animation? A scroll view? If so check this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172255/how-do-i-programatically-zoom-a-uiscrollview). I suggest you change the pinch in your title and description to "zoom in".

Comment: No, I use it in UIImageView and I want to scale the part of image to the whole screen

Comment: So, the UIImageView is not fullscreen and when you press a button you want to animate it to fullscreen? I suggest you edit your question to make it more clear. This way you have more chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: UIImageView is fullscreen and I want to show the part of the image to the full screen after the button pressing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can just start a zoom Animation, if that is all what you want.

**Example:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0,2.0);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your UIImageView inside a UIScrollView to get zooming and panning.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891356/uiimageview-and-uiscrollview-zooming). I've already used this technique and it's the only way I know to do it.

Answer (score -1):

you will want to use the pinchGestureRecognizer :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: With the gesture recognizer it will recognize the pinch gesture. @asmn is asking to do the animation that would happen when pinching but by pressing a button.

Comment: ah ok read the question too fast I guess. Which + button is this anyway in Google Maps?